# Check against two arrays using for loop and if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to run a check against two arrays (one has 4 objects, one just have a few strings) with for loops and if statement for a problem set.

The idea is to use for loop to iterate over every element in the object array and the string array, then use if statement to figure out matches and shove the matching string into a new array. Once all the elements are iterated, it returns the string if there is a matching one.

The problem is the function calls it a day once a single match in the object array is found and returns that only that instead of iterating over the rest of the elements in the object array.

```js
var passengers = [
    { name: ["Michael Jackson"], paid: true }, 
    { name: ["Osama"], paid: false }, 
    { name: ["Harambe"], paid: true },
    { name: ["Pepe"], paid: true },
];

var noFlyList = ["Jimmy", "John", "Pepe", "Osama"];

function checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < noFlyList.length; j++) {
            if (passengers[i].name[0] == noFlyList[j]) {
                var passengerList = [];
                passengerList.push(passengers[i].name[0]);
                return passengerList;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkNotPaid(passengers) {
 return (!passengers.paid);
}

function processPassenger(passengers, testFunction) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        if (testFunction(passengers[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var allCanFly = processPassenger(passengers, checkNoFly);
if (!allCanFly) {
    console.log("We cannot fly because " + checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList) + " is on the no-fly list");
}

var allPaid = processPassenger(passengers, checkNotPaid);
if (!allPaid) {
 console.log("we cannot fly because not all passengers have paid");
}
```

Comment: Love it that 3 seconds after this is posted I've already got a downvote lol

Comment: You're telling it to do so: `return passengerList;`

Comment: @connexo, yeah, but after if statement is done checking for matches in the whole thing, I do want the array to be returned so I can have something at the end

Comment: @connexo is there any way I can have the passengerList as a result of my checknofly function without it ending my for loop in one iteration?

Comment: Also, you keep re-declaring the variable `var passengerList = [];` inside your inner for-loop, emptying it every time.

Comment: @connexo ah good catch, should I declare the passengerList array outside of both for-loop?

Comment: Why do you iterate over `passengers[]` array again in `processPassenger()` function?

Comment: because this is only part of the code, part of the problem sets also requires me to check for whether the passenger have paid or not. I edited my code so the entire thing now shows

Should I be moving the passengers iteration to the checkNotPaid function instead of leaving it in the processPassenger function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this:** having passengerList in the loop make its reinitialized to empty array on each loop, and returning passengerList in the loop makes the loop break once it finishes the first loop

```
function checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList) {
    var passengerList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < noFlyList.length; j++) {
            if (passengers[i].name[0] == noFlyList[j]) {

                passengerList.push(passengers[i].name[0]);

            }
        }
    }
    return passengerList;
}
```

**EDIT**:

change your original processPassenger function to the one below, originally you have only 1 argument passed to your checkNoFly function, where you'd defined it to take 2 arguments, so the false is returned for wrong number of argument, which stop you from getting it the way you want.

```
function processPassenger(passengers, testFunction) {

    if (testFunction(passengers, noFlyList).length !=0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: for your updated question, since for the first check we are returning an array for the single function `processPassenger()` for validation, we can take similar approach for the `checkNotPaid` function to return an array for those who have not paid.

```
function checkNotPaid(passengers) {
    var passengerNotPaid = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        if (!passengers[i].paid) {
            passengerNotPaid.push(passengers[i].name[0]);
        }
    }
    return passengerNotPaid;
}
```

unless you'd want to refactor everything, i think this would be ok.

Comment: What happens there isn't anything in the passengerlist? Would the function return as null or false?

Comment: It would return just what you defined: `[]`, an empty array.

Comment: since it's returning empty array of passengerList, you can check its length

Comment: Nice! But with this, would all paid still work? Since whatever allpaid is returning sure as hell ain't gonna be an array

Comment: Oh and the allpaid function was given to me, I honestly don't know wtf return (!passengers.paid) mean

Comment: ahh ok, you edited your original question and im not aware there's additional functions. just a sec..

Comment: Oh ha sorry about that, I was talking with the thread below :D With this I still get both console.log printed. Even when I change all the paid status to true, the allpaid still gets printed :( In the problem set I think they want us to write processPassenger as a "do it all" function so when more check functions are implemented in the future, we can still use a single process function

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to do so: `return passengerList;` in your inner loop. Also, you keep re-declaring the variable `var passengerList = [];` inside your inner for-loop, emptying it every time.

```js
var passengers = [
  { name: ["Michael Jackson"], paid: true }, 
  { name: ["Osama"], paid: false }, 
  { name: ["Harambe"], paid: true },
  { name: ["Pepe"], paid: true },
];

var noFlyList = ["Jimmy", "John", "Pepe", "Osama"];

function checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList) {
  var passengerList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < noFlyList.length; j++) {
      if (passengers[i].name[0] == noFlyList[j]) {
        passengerList.push(passengers[i].name[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return passengerList;
}
function checkNoPay(passengers) {
  var nonPayers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    if (!passengers[i].paid) { nonPayers.push(passengers[i].name); }
  }
  return nonPayers;
}

var banList = checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList);
if (banList.length) {
  console.log("We cannot fly because " + banList + " is/are on the no-fly list");
}
var unpaidList = checkNoPay(passengers);
if (unpaidList.length) {
  console.log("We cannot fly because " + unpaidList + " has/have not payed the flight");
}
var canWeFly = !(banList.length || unpaidList.length);
console.log(canWeFly ? "We can fly" : "We cannot fly");
```

Comment: Huh, theoretically this should work, but when I tried it with no one in the noFlyList, the console.log still print, just with a blank in the place of checkNoFly

Comment: My bad, I assumed an empty array would evaluate to falsy. Since it doesn't, check array length instead. Updated return line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at js, what does the question mark mean there?

Comment: `return a ? b : c;` is identical to `if (a==true) { return b; } else { return c; }`. It's called *ternary expression*.

Comment: Wait no if the array is empty, then no one is on the no-fly list so the function checkNoFly should return false so processPassenger can return true and then the console.log won't print

Comment: `processPassenger()` is not necessary at all and can be omitted. Check code snippet.

Comment: Yeah I wish... The problem set specified that processPassenger() has to be there :( Also without the processPassenger(), the allpaid thing won't work... Lastly, what does instance of Array do?

Comment: Done. `a instanceof Array` check if a is an array. With all I gave you you should now be in the position to solve your problem.

Comment: Nice! This is certainly one solution, thanks connexo!!

Comment: Tbh it makes me a little sad that a) this wasn't your answer of choice, even though this probably taught you alot more than the other answer, and b) it wasn't even worth an upvote for you.

Comment: I did upvote you, is it not showing? This did teach me a lot and the solution works well, it's just the p set made it so the processPassenger has to be there and Sean W up there figured out a way to include it and have a working solution. Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: Oh because my reputation is <15, my upvote is recorded but not shown :(

Comment: `canWeFly` basically works identical to that function, but if it **has to be a function**, just go `function canWeFly() { return !(checkNoFly(passengers, noFlyList).length || checkNoPay(passengers).length); }` and then `console.log(canWeFly() ? "We can fly" : "We cannot fly");`.